# Using Windows 7 libraries without automatic import into Media Player

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, media, libraries, import

Is it possible to use Windows 7 libraries for Music, Videos, Pictures and Documents, but selectively prevent images in the Pictures library (for instance) from being imported into Windows Media Player?

I would like to assign certain folders to each media library as usual so that I can, for instance, get at all of my videos from the Videos link in the Start Menu and under Libraries in any Windows Explorer window. At the same time, however, I really don't want all of those library items to appear in Media Player. For me the particular issue is that I don't want Media Player to import the pictures in my Pictures library.

If there's not a native option, any good suggestions on work-arounds would also be gratefully appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. Is there any particular reason why you don't want the pictures in WMP's Pictures library?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on any library(Music, Videos, Pictures and etc) and then go to Manage  library. Here you can add/remove folders depending on what you want to have included in your WMP libraries.

PS: I used SOME for Music/Videos/Pictures and etc, according to what you want to modify.